# (JavaScript API 1.3 for Office) Custom Properties add method

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106626/is-it-possible-to-using-custom-properties-javascript-api-1-3-for-office) tho what made me start digging into custom Props again.

I can see that my customProperties are 0 so i assume getCount is somewhat working, even though I'm accessing it through items.length and not customProps.getCount()

Is this still intended or am i just not doing it right and it's possible doing as in the [MS Office Documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/CustomProperties.md)

Now the main part of my question, the add method. Whatever i try it crashes and i get an exception. Can i assume add method is still not properly implemented?

This is all on Word API.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Filipe Heliszkowski Could you show some of your code, particularly the add() call that's throwing the exception, and could you provide the exception error message? Also the CustomProperties object does not have an add method. It has a set method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified this code does not crash Word and works. (assuming you are in latest builds, if your items.count works, this should too.

```js
 Word.run(function (context) {
  context.document.properties.customProperties.add("PropertyName", 1234);
  return context.sync();
  })
```

If this does not work, please reply with your build number.
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I was on my laptop and still needed an update. Newbie mistake. I've tested that code and it works.