# Range.ParentTable giving itemNotFound exception

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

I have written my code in the process of inserting a table to the word document.  My code worked successfully before, but when I run it now, it is giving an exception:

```
"ItemNotFound: ItemNotFound\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:198669)\n   
at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:220646)\n   
at st (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:220733)\n  
at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:220553)\n 
at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:219139)"
```

The error location is showing as

> "errorLocation":"Range.ParentTable"

I have no idea why the code is not running now. I have wrote this code in January. If anyone could, please help me to identify what is wrong in the below code.

my code :

```
 this.insertTable = function () {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        var tableDataJsonString;

        if (range.parentTable != null) {
            var parentTable = range.parentTable;
            var parent_ContentController; //Content controller where the table has been inserted.
            var parent_contentController_id;
            var parent_contentController_tag;
            var parent_name; //Section or Element name
            var parent_id; //Section or Element's id
            var table_style; //Table style
            var count;
            var header_rowCount;
            var body_rowCount;
            var columns;
            var footer_rowCount;

            parentTable.load('rowCount');
            parentTable.load('headerRowCount');

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                if (parentTable.rowCount != null) {

                }
            }).then(function () {
        existing_table.setTableProperties(parent_contentController_id, parent, parent_id, body_rowCount, columns, header_rowCount, footer_rowCount);

                //tableDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(tableData);
                context.sync();

                if (count == null) {

                    _self.selectTableDlg(false, existing_table);
                }
                else if (count != 0) {
                    _self.selectTableDlg(true, existing_table);
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                showAlert('Exception');
            });
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

Code is not going through the 'return context.sync().then(function () {' and return an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if the code was written back in January it was using the PREVIEW APIs, who are subject to change, we apologize about this and thanks for trying them! 
On this case we have  minor change associated on how NULL works, the error is how to check if the table exists. So effectively, you need to make a few changes to make your code work. btw There is a bit more detail [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390979/javascript-api-1-3-for-office-custom-properties-getitemornull/42398350#42398350) who conceptually is the same issue as this one.

Here is some code on how you need to check if the selection is inside a table, and in general how we handle properties and methods that could return null.

Just adjust your code accordingly and it should work.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        //you can get parteTable (will rise an exception if null) or parentTableOrNullObject (never throws an exception and lets you check if its null or not using isNullObject property)
        var myTable = context.document.getSelection().parentTableOrNullObject;
        context.load(myTable);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (myTable.isNullObject)
                    console.log("the selecion is NOT in a table");
                else
                    console.log("the selection is within a table");
            })
    })
```